# Percona XtraBackup questions about full and incremental backups

Tags: mysql, backup, percona, percona-tools

I had a few questions on the Percona forum, and I'm unsure if I was being clear in my questions or not, however I'm curious how full and incremental backups work with XtraBackup.

When doing incremental backups, do I need to have the base dir locally available? I was going to store the backups on AWS but I've had two Percona Staff reply saying yes you do need to keep the full backup on the server physically, but I don't know if I'm being clear because it seems insane to have to have, ultimately, double the storage that your database is - *and* just have it be nothing but your backup sitting there.

In our case our database is roughly 10TB, it seems... odd that I would need to have an extra 10TB of this full backup just "sitting there" for the incremental backup to work. I know there's compression options and such but still.

With that said, what exactly is `--extra-lsn` and/or `--incremental-lsn` used for? It seemed like those would be a way to *not* have the full backup directory physically available.